# Using laser_height_estimation with different hardware configuration

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know some information about [laser_height_estimation](http://ros.org/wiki/laser_height_estimation) package. Is it feasible to be used with my hardware configuration that be found [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/29373/strange-laser_scan_matcher-performance?comment=29388#comment-29388).

Even though the functionality that the package provides seem to suit with what I'm searching for, but, the way the laser scanner is mounted is different. Is it still doable to use this package to estimate height?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29410/using-laser_height_estimation-with-different-hardware-configuration/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The laser height estimation is normally used by providing a small number of laser beams (5 to 20 degrees maybe). They can come from :

- a laser scanner mounted vertically
- a laser scanner mounted horizontally, with the addition of a vertical deflecting mirror

I believe your case describes the first option, so yes, it should work. Make sure you provide an accurate `tf` between your base frame and the laser frame.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-03-09**:
The strange thing is I still cannot invoke "const mav_msgs::" to autocomplete it, as if it's not well configured to find your defined datatype..any ideas?